# How to plot an histogram of the maximum of different dates?

Tags: python, matplotlib, group-by, max, histogram

I am trying to simply plot a histogram for the max value of different dates. I have a DataFrame with many columns including a column `date`and a column `Points`. First, I find the max `Points`for each date with this code:

```
maxnight=new.groupby(["date"], sort=False)["Points"].max()
```

and then I try to plot a histogram of those maxes; I would like to have on the y-axis the frequencies and on the x-axis the max values. I try:

```
plt.hist(maxnight)
```

[image]

But, it does not work, because the smallest value should be 5 and the histogram shows some 0 and 2.5... I do not understand where they come from. I look through all the values in `maxnight` and there is no value under 5

EDIT:
I try with a dummy set of data and it is working. I then found the error is from some outliers that should be there, which is another problems elsewhere.

Comment: Please add data so that your problem can be reproduced.

Comment: Should I delete my question? When I try with some dummy data, everything is working fine. So, the problem is in my datasets ...

Comment: @Jagr Welcome to SO - Please do put that result as an answer! (You can answer your own question and mark it)

Answer (score 0):

Just like as I was doing was working as wanted as shown below :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

new=pd.DataFrame({"date":[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,3,3,4,5,5,5],"Points":[3,2,5,6,8,3,2,8,3,5,6,3,2]})
new
```

`date Points
0   0   3
1   0   2
2   0   5
3   0   6
4   1   8
5   1   3
6   1   2
7   3   8
8   3   3
9   4   5
10  5   6
11  5   3
12  5   2`

```
maxnight=new.groupby(["date"], sort=False)["Points"].max()
maxnight

date
 0    6
 1    8
 3    8
 4    5
 5    6

plt.hist(maxnight)
```

[image]